# How to output game properly

Tags: java, if-statement

I have been trying to fix my snakes and ladders code. For example if Player1's position on the gameboard is 98 and he rolls a 5 Player1's position should be 97. So,(100-98=2,(5-2)=3,100-3=97). I ahve been trying to implement this into my code in the possiblity that either player1 or player2 roll higher than 100.

MY CODE:

```
System.out.println (player1+" Rolled a " + P1Roll ); 
   System.out.println (player2+" Rolled a " + P2Roll); 
   //If player1 position is greater than 100
      if(P1Position+P1Roll>100){
        P1=100-P1Position;
        difference=P1Position-P1Roll;
        P1Position=100-difference;
    }    
    //If palyer2 position is greater than 100
    else if(P2Position+P2Roll>100){
        P2 = 100-P2Position;
        difference=P2Position-P2Roll;
        P2Position=100-difference;
    }    

   System.out.println ("------------------------------------------------------------------------");

   //calculate player positions 
   P1Position = P1Position + P1Roll;      
   P2Position = P2Position + P2Roll;
   //call position methods
   P1Position = Player1(P1Position, P1Roll, snakes, ladder, arrow);           
   P2Position = Player2(P2Position, P2Roll, snakes, ladder, arrow);
  //Print out players current positions
   System.out.println("==========================================================================");                       
   System.out.println (player1+" is currently on square " + P1Position);
   System.out.println (player2+" is currently on square " + P2Position); 
   System.out.println("==========================================================================");
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Please edit your question and add the relevant code type (C#, Java, Javascript) to the TAG. It helps people who want to answer your question know the language of your code in advance.

Comment: Any help would be appreciated

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I make my java program output properly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21149989/how-can-i-make-my-java-program-output-properly)

Comment: You can improve you question by following this:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your calculation it should be

```
difference=P1Roll-P1;
```

And for player 2:

```
difference=P2Roll-P2;
```

And try this more simple way for all cases:

```
P1Position = 100 - Math.abs(P1Position + P1Roll - 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `else` after player 1, unless the methods are called after 1 player rolls.

(Another way of saying it: do both players roll, then you move them? If yes, remove the `else`. If player 1 rolls, and then you update, then keep the `else`. I don't see anything else wrong otherwise).

The `else` statement is treating the conditionals as such: "Is player 1's position plus roll greater than 100? If so, do this block, and that's it. If player 1's position plus roll is *NOT* greater than 100, try the next block". So, if player 1 does have to be "manipulated" using the if block, player two may never get the move to happen.

I hope my answer is not too confusing.